# In C++, how can I initialize memory to mimic other operating systems?

Tags: c++, memory, operating-system, initialization

**Context**: As a teacher assistant, I correct algorithms written in c++. The code must be compiled under Linux and pass the unit tests to have the points (an analysis of the algorithm is also done).
Sometimes, students use techniques that are based on the **non-initialization** of the variables. That is *not an accepted technique* as various operating systems give different outputs. To easily show this, I would like to run my unit tests in different "state of initialization". For example, run the unit tests while the memory is initialized to 0, or initialized to random values.

**Question**: In c++, how can I initialize the memory to specific values such that the unit tests use that initialized memory?

**Some idea of solutions**:

1. I tried to search for a way to initialize all the memory, but I wasn't successful.
2. I could initialize an array of specific values, for example with `new int[1000]();`, but I can't find a way to restrict the c++ program to that initialized memory.

**Specifics** : The students are allowed C++ 14 and previous versions.

Thanks for the help

Comment: just use asan and ubsan to check that there is no undefined behaviour

Comment: @AlanBirtlesI think I'd like to give the students unit tests that already kind of test this for them if possible. 
If not, I note your suggestions

Comment: most use of uninitialised variables will be spotted by the compiler, if you use the correct warning levels

Comment: if you give them build files with the sanitisers enabled then you can. The VS debug allocator does this by default so should be less of a problem on windows (where asan and ubsan are less likely to be available)

Comment: @NeilButterworth I could use flags on my end, but part of the learning process is to compile their own algorithm. Since I'm not the actual teacher, I can't show them how to use flags, because I am not present in class. But I do have some power over the unit tests, which is why I am looking for that kind of solution. I note your suggestion though, thank you

Comment: Just spitballing here: You are testing certain classes provided by your students with you tests, right ? Could you create a byte-array the same size as such an object, fill it with random values (or zeroes), then copy a fresh instance of the object into that memory space by casting the array-pointer ? Or would that crash&burn ?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I cannot force any student to use VS or any other specific IDE. And part of the learning process is for themselves to make build files. Since I'm not the actual teacher, I can't show them how to do build files. But I do have some power over the unit tests, which is why I am looking for that kind of solution. I note your suggestion though, thank you

Comment: @nick That could be an idea, but I don't think it applies here. The students have to implement functions to solve problems by creating an algorithm. The problem lies when they create instances of objects within this function. For example, a student could create a vector, only partially initialize the vector and still use all the values of the vector.

Comment: It is not possible to reliably check if a variable is uninitialized using C++, since the value is indeterminate. Even if you initialize all memory to a specific bit pattern, you still can't check if a variable has that bit pattern without invoking Undefined Behavior. The compiler would be allowed to remove those checks in the name of performance, and it would be correct to do so.

Comment: One option would be to allocate memory, initialise it, and pass it (say, as a "memory area") to your test cases which use placement `new` to initialise "variables" that they use.   Repeat as needed to run test cases with memory initialised in different ways.    That said, I'm not convinced of the value of doing it - relying on "non-initialisation" is a bad habit for a C++ developer - personally, I'd configure the compiler or build scripts used in classes to emit warnings (or, better, errors) and award lower grades to students when they submit code that uses the "non-initialisation" technique".

Comment: For what its worth, you can override the global `operator new` and `operator new[]` to modify how memory is allocated, where you could `memset` all dynamically allocated memory. However, this won't work for function local variables and other objects not dynamically allocated.

Comment: @Peter I totally agree that this is not a good technique and students do lose points in those cases. As I am not the actual Teacher, I am limited in my actions. But I do have power over the unit tests. Thats why I hoped to act on these.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This would not solve my problem since most of the time, this happens with local variables within the algorithms, but I appreciate the comment as this could be helpful in other circumstances.

Comment: The "give a man a fish..." parable applies here, if you do the work for the students they wont learn how to do it themselves, tell them how to use the sanitiser features of whatever platform they're using then they'll know how to use them for future work

Comment: @AlanBirtles As I said, I am not the teacher. I can't just go in class and show them. I do have some power over the unit tests and they have access to the unit tests. I think they can learn for themselves by executing the tests

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type of test you want to do exactly. You may use placement new to emulate uninitialized or zero initialized memory for the array of int like below. This code uses my_array[0] as the variable of summation assuming zero initialized. So, when array is created on uninitialized memory with placement new, calculated summation would be wrong value.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <new>

const int num_array  = 10;
const int num_memory = 100;

int test_calc_sum(void* memory) {
    int* my_array = new(memory) int[num_array];

    for (int i = 1; i < num_array; i++) {
        my_array[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < num_array; i++) {
        my_array[0] += my_array[i];
    }
    return my_array[0];
}

int main() {
    void* mem_uninitialized     = malloc(num_memory);
    void* mem_zeroinitialized   = malloc(num_memory);
    memset(mem_zeroinitialized, 0, num_memory);
    int sum = -1;

    sum = test_calc_sum(mem_uninitialized);
    printf("sum=%d\n", sum);

    sum = test_calc_sum(mem_zeroinitialized);
    printf("sum=%d\n", sum);

    free(mem_uninitialized);
    free(mem_zeroinitialized);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, Thing is, I do not know how the students will build their algorithms, therefore I don't know what structures (array, vector or else) they are going to use. 
Follow up question: Could this work for other structures than arrays, e.g. vectors?